# Costly Phone Number problem <coudnt figure out a solution using graphs>

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

The problem:
The keypad has 11 buttons corresponding to digits from 0 to 9 and one additional button called Add. After pressing any button from 0 to 9, the corresponding digit appears on the screen. The Add button replaces the last two digits appearing on the screen with their sum taken modulo 10. (See sample test for more clarity). If there are less than two digits currently on the screen, pressing Add does nothing.

Each button has a non-negative cost of pressing associated with it. The cost of pressing Add button is always 0. Given the cost of pressing each button and the target phone number, find the minimum cost of feeding that number into the phone screen using a sequence of button presses.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/shortest-path-algorithms/practice-problems/algorithm/costly-phone-number-december-easy-easy-medium/
Here is my approach,
I have considered the numbers 0 to 9 as nodes and the edges as the cost to type a number but we also have to consider the special edges which are dependent on the 2 numbers you entered before, I have tried keeping track of the last two visited edges and modifying Dijkstra's algorithm but couldn't get anywhere with that approach, I'm stuck, any suggestions??

The code in the editorial just uses a nested for loop to get optimal costs for entering digits and then just adding them up but i want to find a way to do it using graphs

Comment: Add your existing approach/code, and the problem that you've run into

Comment: sorry about that, I added the details about the approach I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum cost of a digit can be either of the two cases:

1. The specified cost itself
2. Sum of costs of two different digits

All you have to do is, run a nested loop to test all different pairs of numbers between 10 and 99.

```
new_cost = cost[:]
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        new_cost[(i+j)%10] = min(cost[i]+cost[j], cost[(i+j)%10])
```

Once you have the minimum cost for each digit, you can proceed like a normal problem, since the Add button would have no use.

Comment: It would need to be more recursive. E.g. if 1+1 is cheaper than 2 and 3+3 is cheaper than 6; then maybe (1+1)+(2+2) is the cheapest way of getting 8 (even when 2+6 is more expensive than 8)